# Andriod encryption/decryption

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

My Android phone is dead, but I want to recover my data. I removed eMMC using chip-off and acquired the image/dump file (userdata.bin) using Easy JTAG. The phone had Andriod 9, which uses Full Disk Encryption. I had a passcode on the phone. I tried to recover data from the dump file using crytpsetup command but failed. I know Andriod 9 uses AES. Can I use cryptsetup command to decrypt, as I have the passcode to the phone, and recover my data from the image/dump file (userdata.bin)

Comment: welcome - have you seen this doco? https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/full-disk , see the section titled "storing the encrypted key" which mentions a `HBK` "hardware-bound private key" - no specific experience with this, but from what i can tell you need this to decrypt the `DEK` .. i don't know if you can extract the `HBK` from a dead phone, more https://www.wired.com/story/smartphone-encryption-law-enforcement-tools/ *LHNewman'21*

Comment: Yes, thank you for the resources. I referred to these resources and others also. We can not decrypt the encrypted partition of Android outside of the phone because of the HBK. Moreover, I have not been able to extract the crypto footer containing the DEK, salt, and other encryption parameters necessary for decryption. I am still trying to work it out. Fingers crossed! I will welcome any comments and assistance.